# how to stop jsp from creating sessions on page load

Tags: java, jsp, session, exception, authentication

I know that JSP will create sessions automatically on page load. In my login page I don't want it to create sessions util i click on submit button, and also if user login fails I am sending error message in session so that time it should accept the session already created and after showing error message session should be invalidated. How can i achieve this.

I have tried `session = false` in JSP, this is showing error where i am getting previous session to show error message.

I have also tried page hit count using `application.setAttribute` but this is showing illegalStateException on first load itself.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

This avoids session creation

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
```

Comment: are you looking success and error messages to be displayed as result of the action in your form?